# How can I trigger an action when an element that has a html data attribute is clicked

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How can I trigger an action when an element that has a html data attribute is clicked? I have this element on different places in the same document.

Html element

```
<a href="#" data-trigger="modal" data-target="signInModal">Sign In</a>

<button href="#" data-trigger="modal" data-target="signUpModal">Sign Up</button>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
Let x = getElementByData('data-trigger')
</script>
```

When the any of the html element is clicked, it will return the object of that element that will include data-target

Comment: let x = document.querySelector("[data-attribute]");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)("[data-attribute]") to get the first element with data-attribute or [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)("[data-attribute]") to get all elements that have data-attribute.

```js
// Get all element that have data-field
const allFields = document.querySelectorAll("[data-field]");
console.log(Array.from(allFields));

// Get just the first element that has data-field=name
const elemName = document.querySelector("[data-field=name]");
console.log(elemName);
```

```html
<div data-field="name"></div>
<div data-field="company"></div>
```

**UPDATE**
Now that you have supplied some code it is easier to understand what you where asking for.

```js
function clickHandle(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // Stop the default action (will stop <a> to go to the link, so that you can open your own dialogue or do whatever you want.
  const elem = event.target;
  // your code here. You can access the data attributes via the dataset property:
  console.log(elem.dataset.target);
}

// Get all elements that have data-trigger=modal, and add the clickHandle to them:
document.querySelectorAll("[data-trigger=modal]").forEach(
  (elem) => elem.addEventListener("click", clickHandle)
);
```

```html
<a href="#" data-trigger="modal" data-target="signInModal">Sign In</a>

<button href="#" data-trigger="modal" data-target="signUpModal">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: What do you think OP means by `click event`?

Comment: I think OP want to select an element or elements that have a data-attribute and then add a click event handler to that element. I guess that OP have seen getElementById and want to know how to select an element that has a specified data-attribute.

Comment: We hope ;))))))

Comment: I now understand that my question is vague and am sorry. What i intend doing is to trigger an action after an element with a data attribute is clicked. But am having multiple elements with the same data attribute on the document.

Comment: @DanielGreatmanWalter Edit your question and make it more clear what you want. Pretend that you describe your problem to an intelligent 5-year-old child. Show some code For example, show some html-code where it show your attributes and describe what element you want to detect if they where clicked and  if there are exceptions to this rule.